# How to read a .bmp file identify which pixels are black in Java

Tags: java, image, file-io, bmp

Something like the following... except making it work:

```
public void seeBMPImage(String BMPFileName) throws IOException {
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(BMPFileName));

    int[][] array2D = new int[66][66];

for (int xPixel = 0; xPixel < array2D.length; xPixel++)
    {
        for (int yPixel = 0; yPixel < array2D[xPixel].length; yPixel++)
        {
            int color = image.getRGB(xPixel, yPixel);
            if ((color >> 23) == 1) {
                array2D[xPixel][yPixel] = 1;
            } else {
                array2D[xPixel][yPixel] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem with the above code?

Comment: Why are you testing `if((color >> 23) == 1)`?  That tests if the red component is 128 or more.

Comment: You could simple construct a `Color` object from the RGB `int` value and get's `red`, `green`, `blue` values directly...

Comment: why do assign 1 in the if-branch and also in the else-branch? Probably a bug ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use this:

```
public void seeBMPImage(String BMPFileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(BMPFileName));

    int[][] array2D = new int[image.getWidth()][image.getHeight()];

    for (int xPixel = 0; xPixel < image.getWidth(); xPixel++)
        {
            for (int yPixel = 0; yPixel < image.getHeight(); yPixel++)
            {
                int color = image.getRGB(xPixel, yPixel);
                if (color==Color.BLACK.getRGB()) {
                    array2D[xPixel][yPixel] = 1;
                } else {
                    array2D[xPixel][yPixel] = 0; // ?
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It hides all the details of RGB to you and is more comprehensible.

Comment: Why do you want to read a bitmap from the raw file content on your own? ImageIO does it for you and you can comfortably use BufferedImage to work with it. Sorry, I am confused about your question.

Comment: you are right, and as per your explanation, i am on right path on using ImageIO. i am feeding ImageIO.read(file) to Raster to get raw data so i can read every pixel. What i want to do is separately save every BGR color int three different array of int[] blue, green, red;. but i don't know how to read this from data i am getting from a raster

Answer (score 0):

**mmirwaldt**'s code is already on the right track.

However, if you want the array to visually represent the image:

```
public void seeBMPImage(String BMPFileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(BMPFileName));

    int[][] array2D = new int[image.getHeight()][image.getWidth()]; //*

    for (int xPixel = 0; xPixel < image.getHeight(); xPixel++) //*
    {
        for (int yPixel = 0; yPixel < image.getWidth(); yPixel++) //*
        {
            int color = image.getRGB(yPixel, xPixel); //*
            if (color==Color.BLACK.getRGB()) {
                array2D[xPixel][yPixel] = 1;
            } else {
                array2D[xPixel][yPixel] = 0; // ?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you print the array with a simple 2D array loop, it follows the pixel placement in the input image:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < array2D.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < array2D[x].length; y++)
        {
            System.out.print(array2D[x][y]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

<sup>*Note:* Modified lines are marked by `//*`.</sup>