# How to find the exact color values of a pixel in an image in java

Tags: java, image, rgb

How do I find the exact red or blue or green color of a single pixel in an image in java. Such as (255, 0, 0) would be red, or (0, 255, 0) would be green, etc. Any help? I've been trying to figure this out for quite some time and no answer online or in any of my books has really helped, is this just not possibly? Or is this just horribly inefficient? Any help would be majorly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a .bmp file identify which pixels are black in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015340/how-to-read-a-bmp-file-identify-which-pixels-are-black-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Right shift the rgb/rgba cell bytes and get the lsB . Generally it is R,G,B,A forming a 32-bit integer so you right shift by 8* component index to have a byte ordered at least significant byte. Then use "and" mask to get it.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedImage has a get method that will return an 8 bit color value.

```
public int getRGB(int x, int y)
```

JavaDocs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html